# Making of the dishwasher

Tags: inventorship

In reference to the patent: [US20160278604](https://www.google.com/patents/US20160278604)

I'd need to contact Mr. Alpert or one of the others inventors of this patent for having some more information about this patent and others like this.
Where could I find an e-mail address for contacting them?
One more information: 
has the dishwasher been built or ther is any plans of realising it?
If I wanted to built something like that outside of US, for example in Europe, could I do it?

Thank you in advance for your collaboration.
Best regards.

Vanna Gotti

Comment: Unfortunately, inquiries about the production of inventions/products are  outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

From the form of the document number, this is an application for a patent, not a grant.

Looking at the google patent link you can see "also published as"  US7604012 and US9386902. These are U.S. patents. Ask Patents is a forum for discussing certain aspects of patents and patenting. It is not a direct way to communicate with the inventors. The USPTO has a web site called Public PAIR that provides the public with access to all of the back-and-forth communications between applicants and the USPTO. If you search Ask Patents for PAIR you will find direction on getting to that site. On US9386902, PAIR shows ALPERT, MARTIN A.
26061 ANNESLEY ROAD BEACHWOOD, OHIO 44122 as the assignee (owner) and shows Renner, Otto, Boisselle & Sklar, LLP ; 19th Floor ; 1621 Euclid Avenue ; Cleveland OH; 44115-219 as the attorney of record.